# Joomla: How to add a unique 3 column row only to Frontpage?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to add a unique 3 column row only to Frontpage. I also want to be able to change the contents of these columns via Admin panel. I don't want these 3 columns to be shown on any other page within the website. The contents of these columns could be text, image, etc. And after this row ends, the regular content of the page should begin as usual.

Any help with the above issue is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want a table with 3 columns and 1 row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla is design to work exactly as you are describing. Here are the things you will need to consider -

1. Module position - your template has different positions that modules can be placed in. Does your template have one in the location you would like to put this content? Most template designs will provide you with a map of all the template positions so you can determine this. You can also add ?tp=1 to any URL on the site and it will display all of the positions available. If there is no position where you want to display the content, you can add it to index.php in your template with something like this -

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="name-of-position" style="none" />
```

If you add a new position, you will also need to add the name of the position to templateDetails.xml for it to show up in the positions drop down list. You can also type the name in if you don't want to add it to templateDetails.xml.

2. Content display module - you will need to display the content in a module. If you don't plan to change the content often, you can just use the Custom HTML module and put what ever you need right in to the module directly, then assign the position you determined in step 1 Depending on your needs, you might need to install a module that displays article content or something more suitable, check the Joomla Extension Directory if necessary.

3. Menu assignment - in order for the module to only show up on the home page, you will need to change the Menu Assignment for the module. Change the Menus option to "Select Menu Item(s), then select the home page menu item only.

Comment: Hi Brent, Thanks for the reply. Although I am already using the 1st method that you have stated, the main issue is that I am trying to make 3 different articles appear in 3 adjacent columns. These 3 columns would appear only in the Frontpage and not in any other pages throughout the website. Maybe in a rare instance, I may need it on any other page. But for now, I just need it on the Home page. There is no option to publish an article in a specific module position. I have user1, user2, user3 modules in a div tag but cant publish articles in them. Makes sense? Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Devner, this is not 3 methods, it is 3 steps to 1 method. You need a module that displays article content (step 2), put it in a module position (step 1), then assign it to the home page (step 3). There are a bunch of free modules that allow you to load articles in to a module position. See http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display. You could also use the built in Front Page Blog Layout menu type under the articles menus if you don't have any other component content on the home page.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about Featured articles on the front page.You will have to go to the backend. select content menu > Featured Articles. Add your articles under featured articles category. When you are done, publish them and unpublish those that you dont want to included on the front page.Am sure this will work.